# How to set column value as key in sql json path

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am using Microsoft sql server 2019. My table name is computer

| compid | make | Model | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Dell | Vostro | 2013 |
| 1002 | Dell | Precision | 2014 |
| 1003 | Lenovo | Edge | 2013 |
| 1004 | Lenovo | Horizon | 2014 |

I need a json with the following format

```
[
 {
 'Dell':[{"Model":"Vostro"},{"Model":"Precision"}]      
 },
 {
 'Lenovo':[{"Model":"Edge"},{"Model":"Horizon"}]
 }
]
```

I tried this SQL query

```
Select c1.make,(select Model from Computer c2 where c2.Make=c1.Make for json path) as model from Computer c1 group by c1.make for json path
```

And my output is

```
"[{""make"":""Dell"",""model"":[{""Model"":""Vostro""},{""Model"":""Precision""}]},{""make"":""Lenovo"",""model"":[{""Model"":""Edge""},{""Model"":""Horizon""}]}]"
```

How to add column value as key. Change model key to  Dell, Lenovo

Comment: keys 'Dell', 'Lenovo' should be "Dell', "Lenovo" to be valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below script,

```
;WITH CTE AS (                           
SELECT  
    CONCAT('{','''',Make,'''',':',(SELECT Model FROM #T WHERE Make = T.Make FOR JSON AUTO),'}' ) JSONData
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Make
FROM #T  ) T  )


SELECT '['+STRING_AGG(JsonData,',')+']'
FROM CTE
```

Since the column Naming is dynamic we will not be able to static query for the expected output. So we can STUFF or STRING CONCAT to attain the Output.